# How to remove certain string in an entire column within a HTML table?

Tags: html, jquery, css, xml, xslt

Please help!
I transformed this XML file into HMTL using XSLT and CSS.
Here is the output HTML table :[image]

I want to remove the unnecessary string "1900-01-01T" and ".000" inside these two column.
What should I do? I being trying it for weeks but can’t make any progress.
Below is the XSLT file that I used to transfer the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" exclude-result-prefixes="ss">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>
    <xsl:template match="/ss:Workbook">
        <html>
      <head> 
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </link>
      </head> 
            <body>
            <img src="https://www.colorado.edu/fbs/sites/default/files/article-image/boulder_one_line_0.jpg" alt="University of Colorado Boulder" id="logo"> </img>
            <h2>Schedule of Classes for Fall 2019</h2>
                <table id="table_header" border="1">

                    <xsl:for-each select="ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="ss:Cell/ss:Data">
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the CSS that I used:

```
tbody tr:first-child td {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight:bold;
}


tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e3dbbb;
}

tbody tr {
  background-image: url(noise.png);
}

table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  font-family:arial;
  table-layout: fixed;
  empty-cells: show;
    
}
td {
 border-style : hidden!important;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  max-width:25%;
  max-height:25%;
  float:left;

}



h2 {
   padding: 50px 0; 
 text-align: center;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:arial;

}
```

Comment: your date in rows are string?

Comment: Yes, I think so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because input string length is a constant, the easiest way is below.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <dt>2021-02-23T08:36:40.033</dt>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <root>
            <dt>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(dt, 12, 8)"/>
            </dt>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <dt>08:36:40</dt>
</root>
```